# Matrix Multiplication MPI stop working

Tags: matrix, mpi, multiplication

I am trying matrix multiplication using MPI. My problem is that when I run my code, it prints the message `ARRAY C (C=AxB)` and it stops working. Can anyone help me with that?
That's my code.

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
float **A,**B,**C;
int rownumA,colnumA,c,i,j,k,rank,size,nrank,srowA,srowB,smul,node,node1,temp,rrowA,sender;
int rownumB,colnumB,c1,rc;
MPI_Status stat;
MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
if (size < 2 ) {
  printf("Error\n");
  MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rc);
  exit(1);
  }
nrank=rank-1;
if (rank == 0) 
{

//READ AND FILL FIRST ARRAY
FILE *fp;

colnumA=rownumA=0;
fp=fopen("g.txt","r");
if (fp==NULL) exit(1);

//count rows and lines of 2d array
while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
       if (c==' ')
            colnumA++;

        if (c == '\n')
            rownumA++;
    }
    colnumA=(colnumA/rownumA)+1;
fclose(fp);
// end count

//create dynamic array
A =(float **) malloc(rownumA*sizeof(float*));
for(i=0; i<rownumA; i++){
    A[i]= (float *)malloc(colnumA*sizeof(float));
}


//Fill 2d array from file
fp=fopen("g.txt","r");

for (i=0;i<rownumA; i++){
        for(j=0; j<colnumA; j++){
            fscanf(fp,"%f",&A[i][j]);



        }
}
//end add
fclose(fp);



//READ AND FILL ARRAY B

FILE *fp1;
colnumB=rownumB=0;
fp1=fopen("h.txt","r");
if (fp1==NULL) exit(1);

//count rows and lines of 2d array
while ((c1 = getc(fp1)) != EOF)
    {
       if (c1==' ')
            colnumB++;

        if (c1 == '\n')
            rownumB++;
    }
    colnumB=(colnumB/rownumB)+1;
fclose(fp1);
// end count

//create dynamic array
B =(float **) malloc(rownumB*sizeof(float *));
for(i=0; i<rownumB; i++){
    B[i]= (float *)malloc(colnumB*sizeof(float));
}


//Fill 2d array from file
fp1=fopen("h.txt","r");

for (i=0;i<rownumB; i++){
        for(j=0; j<colnumB; j++){
            fscanf(fp1,"%f",&B[i][j]);



        }
}
//end add
fclose(fp1);


if (colnumA != rownumB ){
    printf("\n Error cant mult!\n");
    exit(1);
}


//create dynamic array
C = (float **)malloc(rownumA*sizeof(float *));
for(i=0; i<colnumB; i++){
    C[i]= (float *)malloc(colnumB*sizeof(float));
}
//Init C with 0
for (i=0;i<rownumA; i++){
        for(j=0; j<colnumB; j++){
                C[i][j]=0;
        }
}
srowA=rownumA/nrank;
rrowA=rownumA%nrank;
smul=0;

for (node=1; node<=nrank; node++)
    {
        if (node<=rrowA)
            temp=srowA+1;
        else
            temp=srowA;

    MPI_Send(&smul,1,MPI_INT,node,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(&temp,1,MPI_INT,node,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(&colnumA,1,MPI_INT,node,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(&colnumB,1,MPI_INT,node,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(&A[smul][0],temp*colnumA,MPI_DOUBLE,node,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(&B,colnumA*colnumB,MPI_DOUBLE,node,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(&rownumA,1,MPI_INT,node,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    smul=smul+temp;     

    }

    //receive results
    for (node1=1; node1<nrank; node1++)
    {
        sender=node1;
        MPI_Recv(&smul,1,MPI_INT,sender,2,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&stat);
        MPI_Recv(&temp,1,MPI_INT,sender,2,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&stat);
        MPI_Recv(&C[smul][0],temp*colnumB,MPI_DOUBLE,sender,2,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&stat);

    }

    //print results
    //Print at file C array
    FILE *fpr;
    fpr=fopen("results.txt","w");
    if (fpr == NULL) exit(1);
    printf("\n\n /// ARRAY C (C=AxB) /// \n \n \n");
    for (i=0;i<rownumA; i++){
            for(j=0; j<colnumB; j++){
                fprintf(fpr,"%0.3f ",C[i][j]);
            }
            fprintf(fpr,"\n");
}
fclose(fpr);


} //end master

if (rank>0)
    {
            MPI_Recv(&smul,1,MPI_INT,0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&stat);
            MPI_Recv(&temp,1,MPI_INT,0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&stat);
            MPI_Recv(&colnumA,1,MPI_INT,0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&stat);
            MPI_Recv(&colnumB,1,MPI_INT,0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&stat);
            MPI_Recv(&A,temp*colnumA,MPI_DOUBLE,0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&stat);
            MPI_Recv(&B,colnumA*colnumB,MPI_DOUBLE,0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&stat);
            MPI_Recv(&rownumA,1,MPI_INT,0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&stat);

        for(k=0; j<colnumB ; k++)
    for(i=0; i<temp; i++)
    for(j=0; j<colnumA; j++)
    {
        C[i][k]+=A[i][j]*B[j][k];
    }

    //send results
        MPI_Send(&smul, 1,MPI_INT,0,2,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&temp,1,MPI_INT,0,2,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&C,temp*colnumB,MPI_DOUBLE,0,2,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

  MPI_Finalize();  
}
```

Comment: In order to get help with error messages on this site, you generally have to put forth more work on your end first. You need to minimize your program to as few lines as possible. Cut out all the I/O, extraneous computation, etc. so you can get to just the problem that you're having and make it easier for other people to read your code and understand it. Usually, when you are working on doing that, you end up finding the problem as you go along and you learn more about the code because you understand what's important and what's not.

Comment: You, my friend, have a deadlock. For the rest, follow the advise of the wise @WesleyBland, and we might help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
//create dynamic array
C = (float **)malloc(rownumA*sizeof(float *));
for(i=0; i<colnumB; i++){
    C[i]= (float *)malloc(colnumB*sizeof(float));
}
```

the upper bound of the `for` loop should be `rownumA`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time..But it doesnt make any difference...Still same problem..